# Team Site Permission Not Showing New Group

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, modern-experience, groups, sharepoint-administration

I have a Modern Team Site and have default permission groups (Owner, Member, Visitor). For the new requirement I have created a new group with new permission level (New Group Test).

[image: New Permission Group]

But when I add users from home page this new group is not showing. There's only Owner and Member.

[image: Not Showing the new group]

I need to assign some users to this new group.

I know I can directly add the users in the group in the first screenshot.

But is it possible to make that group available in the home page as in the second screenshot?

Or by default it only shows Member and Owner option?

Answer (score 0):

This is a default behavior in SharePoint Online team site. By default it only shows the Microsoft 365 groups in **Group membership** Panel.

To add users to the SharePoint groups, you need to go to the Site Settings --> **People and groups**

URL:

```
<siteUrl>/_layouts/groups.aspx
```

To grant permissions users or SharePoint groups, you need to go to the Site Settings --> **Site permissions**

URL:

```
<siteUrl>/_layouts/user.aspx
```